# IOS Swift Tableview:- How Display cell based on content?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i am new to swift kindly need any pointers. 
I have an array like below in table view controller. And i am using cell table label to display the string in **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
var arrTest: [String] = ["test", "test2", "test3", "try", "test4", "try", "test5", "try"] 

cell.textLabel?.text = arrTest[indexPath.row]
```

which works just fine. however i would like to skip to next item in the array each time i hit "**try**". I have tried with below step but not able to achieve what i desired. Any pointers please?

```
var tempIndex: Int = 0
```

Under **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
    if tempIndex < arrTest.count && arrTest[tempIndex] != "try" {
        cell.textLabel?.text = arrTest[tempIndex]
        tempIndex++
    } else {
        tempIndex++
        repeat{
        if tempIndex < arrTest.count && arrTest[tempIndex] != "try" {
                cell.textLabel?.text = arrTest[tempIndex]
                    tempIndex++
                break
            }
            tempIndex++
        } while tempIndex < arrTest.count

    }
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to show cell with following labels only?: "test", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"

Comment: when you get array you can remove from "try" form array and reload tableView

Comment: Yes please only "test", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"
any time "try" appears i has to skip to next item. i dont mind blank cells at the end on the table as well.

Comment: @ShrikantTanwade that works well, but i am working on this example using Realm, which cannot have nil value on strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple way don't display this cell**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    if arrTest[indexPath.row] == "try"
    {
        return 0
    }
    return 44
}
```

**If your cell height is dynamic then use this**

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    if arrTest[indexPath.row] == "try"
    {
        return 0
    }
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return 44.0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove "try" from array and then populate table.

```
let newArrayTest = arrTest.filter() {$0 != "try"} 
yourTableView.reload();
```